# How does one test if some javascript library was loaded succesfully from CDN?

Tags: javascript, cdn, fallback

When downloading javascript files from a CDN, I'd like to provide a local fallback. It's however not always obvious to me how to test if a certain load has succeeded.

For some popular things this is well documented in other StackOverflow questions, e.g. for Bootstrap one just tests `if (window.jQuery)`, `if (window.Popper)`, `if ($.fn.modal)` for its three parts respectively. However, for other libraries this is less obvious:

- For jQuery Validate, I find conflicting information: [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31231370/cdn-fallback-for-dependant-scripts) suggests one can do `if (window.validator)`, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12564896/jquery-validate-cdn-fallback) suggests one needs `if(typeof $().validate == 'undefined')`. What is the difference between these, and why would I need one over the other?
- For less popular libraries, e.g. [balanceText](https://opensource.adobe.com/balance-text/), how should I find out if the library was loaded succesfully?

A general answer/approach would be perfect, but if that's not feasible, I'd be grateful for an answer on these two libraries.

Comment: Just test for the feature that the library is supposed to provide. There are many ways

Comment: How would I test a feature like `balanceText`? I can't think of any object's property changing, it's purely visual?

Comment: That library supplies a global `balanceText` function (according to the docs), whose existence you can test for.

Comment: I see. So simply `if(typeof balanceText == 'undefined')` should be sufficient? Makes sense, thanks!

Comment: or just `if  (window.balanceText)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using loading the script yourself, you can use the `onerror` event on the [`script`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement) element to see if the script loaded instead of checking for side effects. Example:

```html
<script>
function cdnLoaded() {
  console.log('loaded');
}

function cdnError() {
  console.log('not loaded');
  // do error handling here
}
</script>

<script onload="cdnLoaded()" onerror="cdnError()" async src="https://unpkg.com/react@17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script onload="cdnLoaded()" onerror="cdnError()" async src="https://unpkg.com/nothing-here.js"></script>
```